# How to understand golang document?

Tags: go

I am new to Go and would like know how to understand this Go code:

```
func HandleFunc(pattern string, handler func(ResponseWriter, *Request))
```

What do `pattern` and `handler` mean?

Is `handler` just like callback function in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pattern` and `handler` are parameter/variable names. Unlike C, the declaration of types in Go is left to right. i.e. name of variable comes first and then its type. Read more at [Go's declaration syntax](https://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax)

Yes, the `handler` is like JavaScript callback function. Read more at "[First class functions in Go](https://blog.golang.org/first-class-functions-in-go-and-new-go)"